# Does anyone know what the mineral of the year 2023 is?

Tags: geochemistry, mineralogy, minerals, mining, soil-science

I am collecting every mineral of the year since 2012, and I have not found anything on last year's mineral. Thank you.

Comment: As per which organization? IMA? Mincup?

Comment: IMA and Mincup.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the following from [IMA](https://mineralogy-ima-wordpress.website/). Their MOY  will be announced in spring:

> Each spring, CNMNC is electing a “Mineral of the Year”. For 2022, this award has been assigned to lazaraskeite. The mineral was discovered in the area of Oro Valley, north of Tucson, Pima County, Arizona, USA.

We do already have a Mineral Cup  winner from 2023: [Zircon](https://www.mineralcup.org/bracket).

[image]

> Alt text:  A 32-mineral elimination bracket for Mineral Cup 2023 with results from  matches marked, with minerals eliminated left-to-right top-to-bottom culminating in Zircon’s victory. (Retrieved 26 January 2024.)

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Comment: If this was helpful, consider accepting the answer with the check mark.